# locale variable is ignored in symfony translator

Tags: php, symfony

I have installed fos user bundle, i18n routing bundle and translation bundle, and enabled them in the app kernel.

For my config I have:

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    locale: en
```

**config.yml**

```
framework:
    translator:
        enabled: true
    default_locale:  %locale%

jms_i18n_routing: 
    default_locale: %locale%
    locales: [%locale%, fr, es]
    strategy: prefix_except_default
```

And security config with all paths beginning with `^/[a-z][a-z]/`

**security.yml**

```
access_control: 
    - { path: ^/[a-z][a-z]/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/[a-z][a-z]/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/[a-z][a-z]/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    - { path: ^/[a-z][a-z]/profile/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

I have also set routes not paths in `fos_user` config...

Everything is OK with the routes and URLs in the browser.
But the only problem is that views are not translated. They always come with english, the default locale when I have `/fr/my-path`

locale route attribute is `fr`.
`_locale` is `fr`.
`request::locale` is `fr`.
hl cookie is `fr`.

I have set a break point in `Symfony\Component\Translation::trans()` and it seems that the `getLocale()` always return `en`.

Did I have misconfigured something? Or is it may be a bug?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I found a partial solution it work for me! we have to set _locale defined in appKernel using a variable defined in session that contains the current language. If anyone have a better solution then he is welcome.

Comment: Maybe it's better create an event listener and register it as a service and notify symfony?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html